# How-to search on a document with kind of join

Tags: c#, ravendb

Next to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141213/how-to-create-index-on-multiple-documents-with-reducing). I want to perform lucene query search now.

Here is my models :

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class BookFavorite
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string BookId { get; set; }
}
```

So, I want to search on field "Title" of Book, but only in books that are in favorites. So i need to make a kind of join between Book and BookFavorite and index Title Field.

I've tried with MultiMap Index, but i found it difficult to make it work.

Any help ?
Thanks.

EDIT : The MultiMap Index

```
public class BookFavoriteSearchIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<BookFavoriteSearchIndex.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Abstract { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public BookFavoriteSearchIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Book>(books => from book in books
                              from tag in book.Tags
                              select new
                                         {
                                             BookId = book.Id,
                                             Title = book.Title,
                                             Description = book.Description,
                                             Abstract = book.Abstract,
                                             Tag = tag
                                         });

        AddMap<BookFavorite>(bfs => from bf in bfs
                                    select new
                                               {
                                                   BookId = bf.BookId,
                                                   Title = (string)null,
                                                   Description = (string)null,
                                                   Abstract = (string)null,
                                                   Tag = (string)null
                                               });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.BookId
                                into g
                                select new
                                           {
                                               BookId = g.Key,
                                               Title = g.Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                               Description = g.Select(x => x.Description).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                               Abstract = g.Select(x => x.Abstract).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                               Tag = g.Select(x => x.Tag).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                           };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the current MultiMap index you have?

Comment: Just edited. Note that i need to search across all theses fields, including tags, which makes me another problem since it seems to index only one value and not all tag values...

Answer (score 0):

Book titles don't change that often, so why don't you include the `Title` inside the `BookFavourite`, like this:

```
public class BookFavorite
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string BookTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just query against the `BookTitle` in the `BookFavourite` objects.

You'll be duplicating data, but it's data that doesn't change, so you don't have to worry about updating it.

**Update (as per the extra info)**

What about storing an `IsFavourite` field in the `Book` class, you can then use that in your queries? You just need to maintain this field as book are "favourited".

```
public class Book
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Actually, here is a very very simplified model i show in the question. But really i've a more complex model with fields like Description, Collection of Tags, etc.. and i need to search accross all theses fields so i don't want to duplicate all that fields and i don't want to maintain data consistency between theses documents

Comment: The IsFavorite field isn't an option for me since a favorite is per user. Maybe favorite doesn't mean for you, but it's a kind of bookmarks. So i think it makes sence to make a document linking the bookid and userid.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this answer should solve your problem of linking Book and BookFavorite in a similar question I asked:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296212/1353377)

EDIT: It assumes your Book and BookFavorite are contained in individual Lists though

Comment: I'm talking about ravendb, i can't use linq based joins.